# Mapping a function to a dotted pair

Tags: common-lisp, elisp

I want to map a function, `(lambda (x) (+ x 1))`, to a dotted pair `'(1 . 2)`, to get another dotted pair, `'(2 . 3)`. I have tested the below code to no avail:

```lisp
(defun mapdot (func coll)
  ((funcall func (car coll)) . (funcall func (cdr coll))))
```

```lisp
ELISP> (mapdot (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) '(1 . 2))
*** Eval error ***  Invalid function: (funcall func (car coll))
```

How can I achieve such behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had problems with your first attempt because it tries to use `(funcall func (car coll))` as the name of a function to call - which of course doesn't work. To make the mistake clearer, it's as if you were doing this:

```
ELISP> ((list))
*** Eval error ***  Invalid function: (list)
```

The solution would be to either use `cons` or a quasiquote:

```
ELISP> (defun mapdot (func coll)
         (cons (funcall func (car coll)) (funcall func (cdr coll))))
mapdot
ELISP> (mapdot (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) '(1 . 2))
(2 . 3)
```

```
ELISP> (defun mapdot (func coll)
         `(,(funcall func (car coll)) . ,(funcall func (cdr coll))))
mapdot
ELISP> (mapdot (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) '(1 . 2))
(2 . 3)
```

Comment: I prefer the one using quasiquote more. Thanks for pointing out the extra parentheses.

Answer (score -1):

There had been an easy solution I overlooked since I was reluctant to switch to an imperative style: to create a dummy list and manually set the `car` and `cdr` of it.

```lisp
(defun mapdot (func coll)
  (let ((temp-list '(1 2)))
    (progn
      (setf (car temp-list) (funcall func (car coll)))
      (setf (cdr temp-list) (funcall func (cdr coll)))
      temp-list)))
```

Now it runs just fine:

```lisp
ELISP> (mapdot (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) '(1 . 2))
(2 . 3)
```

Comment: that's usually not a good idea, because the code is trying to modify a literal cons cell. It is not allocating a fresh cons cell.

Comment: @RainerJoswig True, but the cons cells `1` and `2` are created just to be destructively updated, so I guess `setf`-ing individual cons cells may be acceptable under restricted conditions like this.

Comment: No, you don't create a cons cell. You are modifying the source code. The list (1 2) is literally in the source code. Every call to mapdot modifies the cons cell bound to TEMP-LIST and the function then always returns this single cons cell. If you use the output of this function, older results get modified, too - since the result is always the same object, the same cons cell.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I have not fully understood your comment, but I have definitely observed that successive calls to `mapdot` changes the past results. Do you mean that `'(1 2)` exists somewhere in the memory beforehand, and I change that piece of memory everytime I call `mapdot` (Therefore, old results gets changed altogether)?

Comment: Yes, the objects that make up `(1 2)`: two cons cells, two numbers and NIL. They can also be written as `(1 . (2 . nil))`. You probably wanted to write `(1 . 2)`. But, anyway, that object is a part of the running code, not a data object. If you want to create new fresh cons cells, you would need to call the function CONS (or similar functions).

Comment: @RainerJoswig After thinking for some while, I was totally blown away by Lisp's behavior. By defining `mapdot` as above, I literally told Lisp to change my `mapdot` to bind `temp-list` to some other cons cell (call it `c1`). A second call to `mapdot` makes the control jump to now-modified `mapdot`, which updates `c1` into say, `c2`, and return that cons cell `c2`, while changing `mapdot` to bind `temp-list` to `c2` the next call. (So, that cons cell constituting `mapdot` stays there, only changing its contents.) Wow. This is such an interesting behavior; code is a list made up of cons cells.

Comment: This is the same in many other programming languages: a program modifies literal data. In Common Lisp this behavior has undefined consequences and you may see some surprising effects, Imagine the code is in ROM (read only memory), then it might even fail.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Yes. That's a sure-fail scenario. What I was most impressed by is the fact that in Lisp, there can be self-modifying functions: and I unknowingly wrote one.